# SNMP 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' error

Tags: c#, exception, snmp, mib

Trying o understand and learn what is snmp by reading and executing examples on Newtork Programming book. 
I have an error (on string MIB Structure) when I executed the program (on page 435). I have just inserted SNMP class(page 430) to project.

The problem is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in SimpleSNMP.exe

The code line

```
response = conn.get("get", argv[0], argv[1], "1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0");
```

I want to learn status od remote devices by using snmp.Any helpful, useful and working c# SNMP example is appreciated.

All code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace SimpleSNMP
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] argv)
        {
            int commlength, miblength, datatype, datalength, datastart;
            int uptime = 0;
            string output;
            SNMP conn = new SNMP();
            byte[] response = new byte[1024];
            Console.WriteLine("Device SNMP information:");
            // Send sysName SNMP request and get the response
            response = conn.get("get", argv[0], argv[1], "1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0");
            if (response[0] == 0xff)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No response from {0}", argv[0]);
                return;
            }
            // Get the community name and MIB lengths from the packet
            commlength = Convert.ToInt16(response[6]);
            miblength = Convert.ToInt16(response[23 + commlength]);
            // Extract the MIB data from the SNMP response
            datatype = Convert.ToInt16(response[24 + commlength + miblength]);
            datalength = Convert.ToInt16(response[25 + commlength + miblength]);
            datastart = 26 + commlength + miblength;
            output = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response, datastart, datalength);
            Console.WriteLine(" sysName - Datatype: {0}, Value: {1}",
            datatype, output);
            // Send a sysLocation SNMP request
            response = conn.get("get", argv[0], argv[1], "1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0");
            if (response[0] == 0xff)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No response from {0}", argv[0]);
                return;
            }
            // Get the community name and MIB lengths from the response
            commlength = Convert.ToInt16(response[6]);
            miblength = Convert.ToInt16(response[23 + commlength]);
            // Extract the MIB data from the SNMP response
            datatype = Convert.ToInt16(response[24 + commlength + miblength]);
            datalength = Convert.ToInt16(response[25 + commlength + miblength]);
            datastart = 26 + commlength + miblength;
            output = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response, datastart, datalength);
            Console.WriteLine(" sysLocation - Datatype: {0}, Value: {1}",
            datatype, output);
            // Send a sysContact SNMP request
            response = conn.get("get", argv[0], argv[1], "1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4.0");
            if (response[0] == 0xff)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No response from {0}", argv[0]);
                return;
            }
            // Get the community and MIB lengths
            commlength = Convert.ToInt16(response[6]);
            miblength = Convert.ToInt16(response[23 + commlength]);
            // Extract the MIB data from the SNMP response
            datatype = Convert.ToInt16(response[24 + commlength + miblength]);
            datalength = Convert.ToInt16(response[25 + commlength + miblength]);
            datastart = 26 + commlength + miblength;
            output = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response, datastart, datalength);
            Console.WriteLine(" sysContact - Datatype: {0}, Value: {1}",
            datatype, output);
            // Send a SysUptime SNMP request
            response = conn.get("get", argv[0], argv[1], "1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0");
            if (response[0] == 0xff)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No response from {0}", argv[0]);
                return;
            }

        // Get the community and MIB lengths of the response
        commlength = Convert.ToInt16(response[6]);
        miblength = Convert.ToInt16(response[23 + commlength]);
        // Extract the MIB data from the SNMp response
        datatype = Convert.ToInt16(response[24 + commlength + miblength]);
        datalength = Convert.ToInt16(response[25 + commlength + miblength]);
        datastart = 26 + commlength + miblength;
        // The sysUptime value may by a multi-byte integer
        // Each byte read must be shifted to the higher byte order
        while(datalength > 0)
        {
        uptime = (uptime << 8) + response[datastart++];
        datalength++ ;
        }
            Console.WriteLine(" sysUptime - Datatype: {0}, Value: {1}",
        datatype, uptime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The program presumably wants command line arguments that you are not supplying.

Comment: With how many arguments are you calling your application? it expects at least 2

Comment: I am using WinDump program to monitor network trace. Program make fault on MIB structure even I try "1.3" or "1".

Comment: @AlexK. I think the program does not wants command which already have get (this method is in SNMP class)

Comment: It certainly does: `argv[0]` attempts to read the first command line param, if you don't provide one attempting to access `argv[0]` will raise `IndexOutOfRangeException` which is exactly what you see.

Comment: First, you should make it very clear which book you are referring to. Merely saying "Network Programming" is useless for others to locate the materials. Second, when there is an exception, state clearly the exception information you get from Visual Studio or console dialog, as it contains the line numbers and the call stack, which indicates the problematic line of code, and you don't waste others' time to guess. Lastly, "1" is not a valid OID according to the standard. Valid OIDs must be at least of two components, like "1.3".

Comment: Dear helpful guys, I apoligize for taking your time. Honestly I have just basic knowledge and no more. I dont know what is what. Now i am looking snmpsharpnet. Again if you suggest to me useful book I will read them.thx

Comment: Open source projects such as snmpsharpnet or sharpsnmplib contains all necessary bits for you to explore than the simple sample in a book. Personally, there is no "useful" book for SNMP C# at all. You need to understand SNMP from the general books and apply the knowledge to C# on your own.